# Замена определенных конструкций текста во всех файлах, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Господа, подскажите пожалуйста

У меня есть куча MD файлов, в которых есть ссылки на соседний html файлик. Хочу сделать скрипт, который во всех файлах в указанной папке будет заменять конструкцию вида `[xxx_name](../ReferenceManual.html#operation/xxx)` на `<a href="../ReferenceManual.html#operation/xxx" target="_blank">xxx_name</a>')`
чтобы потом после конвертации MD файла в html ссылки открывались в новой вкладке

Я только начинаю знакомится с питоном и у меня получилось написать простой скриптик, который заменяет указанный текст на другой (в интернете полно примеров), но тут дело в том, что текст `xxx_name` и `xxx` всегда разный и если использовать простой скрипт, то нужно заранее указать миллион вариантов, которые нужно заменить

Видимо нужно использовать библиотеку re, но пока нет идей как ее можно использовать

Пока что есть только такое:

```
files_for_replacement = (         // не получается указать папку
  "/home/user/Documents/1.md",    // для поиска всех документов :(
  "/home/user/Documents/2.md",
  "/home/user/Documents/3.md",
  "/home/user/Documents/4.md",
) 

for files_for_replacement in files_for_replacement:
  with open (files_for_replacement, 'r') as f:
    old_data = f.read()
    old_data1 = f.read()

    new_data = old_data.replace( 
      '["get data"](../ReferenceManual.html#operation/getData)', '<a href="../ReferenceManual.html#operation/getData" target="_blank">"get data"</a>'
    )
    new_data1 = old_data1.replace(
      '["put file"](../ReferenceManual.html#operation/putFile)', '<a href="../ReferenceManual.html#operation/putFile" target="_blank">"put file"</a>'
    )
  with open (files_for_replacement, 'w') as f:
    f.write(new_data)
    f.write(new_data1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
t1=open('/path/to/file.md').read()
t2=re.sub(r'\[([\w\s]+)\]\(([\w:\/\.\-]+)\)', r'<a href="\2" target="_blank">\1</a>', t1)
open('/path/to/file.md').write(t2)
```

как-то так примерно

Comment: получилось, спасибо большое)

единственное, не работает если в заменяемом тексте есть символ `#`, но я сделал так `re.sub(r'\["([\w\s]+)\"]\(([\w:\/\.\-(#operation)]+)\)` и вроде заработало, но тут оказалось, что у меня есть два вида ссылок - на файлы md `["example"](1-example.md#test)` и на файлы html `["put file"](../ReferenceManual.html#operation/putFile)` и мне надо, чтобы он менял ссылки только там, где есть конструкция `#operation...` (т.е. ссылки на файлы html), а то как я сделал обрабатывает вообще всё, где есть `#`(